# In jfet, why Vgs is half the cutoff voltage when the source resistor is same as the ohmic resistance of the jfet?

Tags: jfet

\$R_{DS}\$ is the resistance of jfet in the ohmic region.  When the source resistor is matched to this value,  my textbook seems to say that \$V_{GS}\$ will be half the cutoff/pinchoff voltage. Why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFETs have a square-law current versus gate voltage.

thus: \$ I_d = \kappa \times (V_g - V_t)^2 \$

the derivative \$ \frac{d I}{d V_g} = \kappa \times [2 \times (V_g - V_t) ] \$

Which tells us what?

The ohmic resistance of the FET is the transconductance,

or \$ \frac{1}{d I / d V_g}\$

thus ohmic resistance = \$ \frac{1}{[\kappa \times 2 \times (V_g - V_t)]} \$

Is that "2" of use in understanding?

================================

becca what did you learn? does the math work?

Comment: I see that the curve is a parabola with vertex at cutoff voltage. Thus the normalized current will be 1/4 when the gate voltage is 1/2. I still don't see how making the source resistor value equal to the ohmic resistance fixes the Q point at (1/2, 1/4). Thank you :)